# Multiple identity columns or a way to auto increment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (`tOrder`) that has the following structure in SQL Server 2008

```
orderID (int) - this is currently the primary key and the identity field.
name(varchar)
address(varchar)
groupID (int) - now this field i need to also auto increment, but at the same time i want to be able to insert values into.
```

My data would look something like:

```
1 - john - address1 - 1
2 - mary - address2 - 1
3 - mary -address3 - 2
4 - jane - address4 - 3
```

where order IDs 1 and 2 share the same group , while 3 and 4 are in their own.

Many orders can have same `groupID`, but when I insert an order of a new group, I would like the `groupID` to be auto populated with the next sequence number automatically, while at the same time allowing me to insert duplicate `groupID` for different orders if I need to.

Hope this makes sense.

How do I go about doing this? (I'm using c# in the back end, if that makes any difference)

Comment: Have you considered creating a "group" table with an Identity as primary key and creating a foreign key that references the "group" table from tOrders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a trigger on your torder table (not a fan of triggers, but given your criteria, can't think of another option).

```
CREATE TRIGGER tOrder_trigger
   ON  tOrder
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
   UPDATE tOrder
   SET groupid = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(groupid),0) + 1 FROM tOrder)
   FROM INSERTED AS I
   WHERE I.groupid IS NULL
   AND tOrder.orderid = I.orderid;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d88a/1)

This checks if the inserted record has a `NULL` groupid using `INSERTED`, and if so, updates the table to the `MAX(groupid) + 1`, using `COALESCE` to check for `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new "groups" table with an identity to ensure uniqueness as follows:

```
create table tOrders(
    orderID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    name varchar(30),
    address varchar(60),
    fkGroup int
);
create table tGroups(
    groupID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    description varchar(50)
);

ALTER TABLE tOrders 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (fkGroup) REFERENCES tGroups(groupID);
```

You would, of course have to either supply a groupID for the IDENTITY of a newly inserted tGroup (groupID) value.

This [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eb6e) demonstrates one way of populating the tables.